# Get last 10 photos from iPhone using AssetLibrary, Corelocation deprecation issue on ios 6.1.3

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

App tries to access photos from phone library. Works well on ipod (5.1.something) iPhone5 (6.1.4), all simulators, but crashes on iPhone 4S(6.1.3).

All checks (location services, photo library access) are there w.r.t ios version.

Console LOG:
: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary

Jul 31 12:03:00 ABC's-iPhone awdd[296] : CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.

BTW below code fetches last 10 photos from the photo library. If exist. Before calling this method check for location is made using [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus].

```
- (void) getRecentPhotos
{
    if(! oneTimeFetch) // to prevent location delegate from calling this method.
    {
        oneTimeFetch = TRUE;

        NSLog(@"getRecentPhotos");

        recenPicScroll.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;

        [self.recentPicsArr removeAllObjects];

        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 6.0)
        {
            NSLog(@"IOS version 6.0 and above, need to check for photo access");

            if ([ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
            {
                NSLog(@"Photo ACCESS ALLOWED");
                // just execute the code after loop ends. Else return :).
            }

            else
            {
                recentPicView.hidden = TRUE;

                NSLog(@"PLEASE ALLLOW PHOTO ACCESS");

                return;
            }
        }

        recentPicView.hidden = FALSE;
        loadingAI.hidden = FALSE;


        ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        [al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos

                          usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
         {
             [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

             [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
              {
                  if([group numberOfAssets] == 0)
                  {
                      recentPicView.hidden = TRUE;
                      return;
                  }

                  int startIdx = [group numberOfAssets]- 10;  // Start from 10th last

                  if (asset)
                  {
                      //NSLog(@"asset Index: %d",index);

                      ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

                      CGImageRef imgRef = [rep fullResolutionImage];

                      if(group.numberOfAssets > 10) // upto 10
                      {
                          if(index >= startIdx)
                          {
                              [self.recentPicsArr  addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef]];

                              if(index == [group numberOfAssets] - 1)
                              {
                                  [self addPicsToScrollV];
                              }
                          }
                      }

                      else if (group.numberOfAssets <= 10) // get less than  10 photos
                      {
                          [self.recentPicsArr  addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef]];

                          if(index + 1 == group.numberOfAssets)
                          {
                              [self addPicsToScrollV];
                          }
                      }

                      else
                      {
                          recentPicView.hidden = TRUE;
                      }
                  }
              }];
         }

        failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"You must allow the app to fetch your photos");
         }

         ] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-11948?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: I am not using any of those deprecated methods. Do I have to insert a key in the plist ? mentioned in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AlAsset library requires location services to be enabled, I couldn't ignore the location check.

And Since iOS 6.0 user can even prevent the app from accessing the photo library so AssetLibrary authorisation was also required.

Solution for me was to use [self.locMgr stopUpdatingLocation] in the below delegate:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if(status == 1 || status == 2)
    { 
        NO_LOCATION_ALERT // User denied location. Don't start the activity for fetching photos
    }

    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
       //Start fetching fotos
    }

    else
    {
        // This is for the first time, when user hasn't made any choice. So leave it blank.
    }

    [self.locMgr stopUpdatingLocation];  // SOLUTION
}
```